# 1 of n Multisig Scriptless Scripts?

Tags: schnorr-signatures

I know MuSig makes n of n multisig  scriptless. However, can we also aggregate multiple internal public keys in one public key, and unlock funds using either one of the internal public keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MuSig does not support m-of-n multisig, so you should use a threshold signature scheme like this:

http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2001/corr2001-13.ps